# Binding Large html using innerHTML in angular ssr

Tags: angular, angular-ssr

I am getting a blog content from api that have a very huge amount of html and need to bind in a div tag in angular SSR. server side rendering is must.

```
<div [innerHtml]="cmsContent.content! | noSanitizePipe:'html'"></div>
```

Data are binding but its take too much of time to load in browser.

Is there any alternative way to bind without affecting SSR?

I tried binding with innerHtml and html sanitize but its take too much time to load in browser.

Comment: I have a similar problem doing SSR on backend blog content. Unfortunately, [hydration](https://angular.io/guide/hydration) requires that the server and client html have the same structure. I tried directly inserting the content into html on the server side, but the content did not get preserved (although the title did). Trying to work around this by extracting and saving the content from the DOM in plain javascript before Angular starts, then reinserting. This would avoid fetching CMS data twice

Comment: I managed to preserve the content through hydration. Can you show how you obtain the CMS data into your component? How does your server insert it?